# Pair wise swap in link list in c++

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
void pairWiseSwap(struct node *head)
{
// The task is to complete this method
   if(!head || (head && head->next==NULL))
   return;

   if(head->next!=NULL)
   {
     int tmp = head->next->data;
     head->next->data = head->data;
     head->data = tmp;
     pairWiseSwap(head->next->next);
   }
 }
```

swap elements pairwise. 
How this code is working?
How back recursion call is working?

Comment: Why not [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

Comment: ... because this is C code rather than C++

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about this code?  What is it doing that you don't expect, and what do you expect?

Comment: Side-note: It is not necessary to re-check `head` on the right side of the `||` operator. Both the C and C++ standards guarantee that if the left side of a logical OR operator evaluates to true, the right side is not evaluated. Therefore `(!head || head->next==NULL)` is safe, unless your compiler doesn't conform to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the function says it swaps the data in each pair of cells (not the cells themselves).

---

The exchange of data from a cells with the next one is very visible :

> ```
> int tmp = head->next->data;
> head->next->data = head->data;
> head->data = tmp;
> ```

---

> How back recursion call is working?

the call with `pairWiseSwap(head->next->next);` bypass the couple of cells whose data was swap to redo on the next ones.

---

Let see an example with that full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  struct node * next;
  int data;
};

void pairWiseSwap(struct node *head)
{
// The task is to complete this method
   if(!head || (head && head->next==NULL))
     return;

   if(head->next!=NULL)
   {
     int tmp = head->next->data;
     head->next->data = head->data;
     head->data = tmp;
     pairWiseSwap(head->next->next);
   }
}

struct node * mk(int d, struct node * nx)
{
  struct node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  if (n != NULL) {
    n->data = d;
    n->next = nx;
  }

  return n;
}

void pr(struct node * head)
{
  while (head) {
    printf("%d ", head->data);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct node * head = mk(0, mk(1, mk(2, mk(3, mk(4, mk(5, NULL))))));

  printf("before : ");
  pr(head);

  pairWiseSwap(head);
  printf("\nafter:   ");
  pr(head);
  putchar('\n');

  /* free resources */
  while (head) {
    struct node * n = head->next;

    free(head);
    head = n;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra h.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
before : 0 1 2 3 4 5 
after:   1 0 3 2 5 4
```

---

Note

```
if(!head || (head && head->next==NULL))
  return;
```

can be just

```
if ((head == NULL) || (head->next==NULL))
  return;
```

because if *head* is not null in the left part of `||` it is useless check again it is not null in the right part

---

If the recursion is done on `head->next` rather than `head->next->next` the function does a kind of rotate and the result is `1 2 3 4 5 0`